# Why I can't use lambda expression inside Tuple.Create?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, tuples, predicate

I know that the compiler can cast from lambda expression to Predicate.

For example:

```
Predicate<int> p = x => true;
```

is good.

But when I want to create a tuple that holds a Predicate.
I tried to do this (simplified version):

```
Tuple<Predicate<int>> t;
t = Tuple.Create(x => true);
```

and I got the compilation error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Tuple.Create(T1)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

My question is what this is an error, where is the ambiguity here?

(I know I can fix it by casting:`t = Tuple.Create((Predicate<int>)(x => true));` 
but I want  to understand why the first way is not good, and also I want not to do the casting to save typing :)

Comment: Tuple.Create has nothing to do `t` declared ahead. So compiler can't infer x's type.

Comment: `t = Tuple.Create<Predicate<int>>(x => true);` would work. You have to specify the type somehow. Just `x => true` is definition of ambiguous.

Comment: Or write your own factory method: `Tuple<Predicate<int>> CreateTuple(Predicate<int> predicate) { return Tuple.Create(predicate); }`

Comment: Just to make it clear for you. this will work  `t = Tuple.Create((Predicate<int>) (x => true));`. why? because you have casted `x => true` to known type `Predicate<int>` and you must know that `x => true` can have thousands of meanings to the compiler. anyway because `Tuple.Create` is generic type you can specify type instead of casting which is better and explained in answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where is the ambiguity here?

The ambiguity here is that the compiler doesn't attempt to infer the lambda expression passed to `Tuple.Create` based on the left hand side which already declares the desired type. What happens is *type inference algorithm* kicks in (regardless of you declaring the type of the variable), and fails to find a suitable match to your lambda expression as it doesn't have enough information.

This can be easily fixed with declaring the type of the tuple and explicitly telling the compiler how to infer the lambda expression:

```
t = Tuple.Create<Predicate<int>>(x => true);
```

If you want to get into the type inference algorithm and see why it fails:

Given:

```
Tr M<X1…Xn>(T1 x1 … Tm xm)
```

> With a method call of the form M(E1 …Em) the task of type inference is
>   to find unique type arguments S1…Sn for each of the type parameters
>   X1…Xn so that the call M(E1…Em) becomes valid.

Now we start:

> 7.5.2.1 The first phase:
>
> For each of the method arguments Ei:
>
> If Ei is an anonymous function, an **explicit parameter type inference
>   (§7.5.2.7) is made from Ei to Ti**

So we look what explicit parameter type inference does:

> 7.5.2.7 Explicit parameter type inferences
>
> An explicit parameter type inference is made from an expression E to a type T in the following
>   way:
>
> · If E is an **explicitly typed anonymous function** with
>   parameter types U1…Uk and T is a delegate type or expression tree type
>   with parameter types V1…Vk then for each Ui an exact inference
>   (§7.5.2.8) is made from Ui to the corresponding Vi.

Your anonymous function isn't explicitly type, so the compiler has no way of doing an exact inference from the parameter type Ui..Uk to proper overload of `Tuple.Create`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It helped me understand it better, (though it is still little vague to me, not your fault, I need to learn it more).

Comment: @Erez It'll come with time. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Tuple.Create` method takes generic type parameters. The compiler can usually guess what those types are when you call it. However with the predicate, there is no way it can figure it out. Some solutions are:

```
Predicate<int> p = x => true;
var t = Tuple.Create(p);
```

Or I suggest you just specify the type parameter:

```
var t = Tuple.Create<Predicate<int>>(x => true);
```

Comment: Your first example still won't compile; I think you meant `Tuple.Create(p)`

Answer (score 2):

To give a slightly different perspective than the existing answers:

The C# language is designed so that in

```
t = Tuple.Create(x => true);
```

the type of `Tuple.Create(x => true)` does not depend on `t`. This makes it easier to parse C#, to make it easier to reason about C# code, to make it easier to implement decent error messages for invalid C# code.

Now, given that, how should the compiler determine that `Tuple.Create(x => true)` should treat `x => true` as a `Predicate<int>`, and not, say, a `Func<int, bool>`? There isn't enough information to determine that, except in a location where the compiler by design doesn't check.